# How to handle htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, https, xmlhttprequest

Folks,

I am newbie to SSL certificates.

We just put SSL for our website, which developed PHP codeigniter framework.

My site is under https protocol. If I call the other url from that website's page, it also showing in https prefixed..

That child url is third party url, which needs to call from javascript. It is available in only http, not in https.

I am mentioning

`function {
           host:'abc.des.com';
          }`

In my firebug console the response shows https prefixed before this url. But I want response as in only http.

Hope someone will guide me in this.

Comment: are you calling using PHP or javascript? Can you try to specify the full url see if it works? e.g. `http://abc.des.com/script.php`, you may run into trouble with chrome browser if calling unsafe (http) from safe (https) site i think...

Comment: Post some code as how are you calling this third party URL?

Comment: Yes, I am calling this url from function... the sample code is       `function load() {
newHost = 'abc.com';
}`

Comment: it is not possible of doing  like the ordinary point out `function load() { newHost = 'http://abc.com'; }`